# Why is this query blocking other queries from running?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here's my entire script:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Products_temp') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #Products_temp
END

GO

SELECT p.product_id, p.price, p.cost, i.qty
INTO #Products_temp
FROM   Warehouse_Products p WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Warehouse_Inventory i WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON p.product_id = i.product_id

GO

DELETE FROM cache.Products

GO

INSERT INTO cache.Products SELECT * FROM #Products_temp
```

For some reason the `SELECT .. INTO` part was stuck in a `RUNNABLE` state for 3 hours when typically the entire script takes 6-7 minutes to finish. This was blocking all my other queries, which is exactly why I wrote this script in the first place. I wanted to prevent blocking any other table/script by using a temporary table, what am I doing wrong here? Any advice?

Comment: Are you *sure* it wasn't the `DELETE` that was blocking? Considering you're deleting all the rows, why not `TRUNCATE` the table?

Comment: As a side note, I also wouldn't trust a table where all its contents was created by a query using `NOLOCK` if those table's data is likely to change in any way while the `SELECT ... INTO` is running.

Comment: @ThomA Yes when I went into activity monitor, right clicked the query that was blocking everything and hit 'Details'. It showed the `SELECT .. INTO` section of the query, once I killed it everything was unblocked.  Also `NOLOCK` is fine here because the table's data is scheduled to change at a different time from this script.

Comment: When it is blocked you need to see what the wait type is (lock?) and assuming it is a lock what resource it is.

Comment: Was it blocking, or was it blocked by something else? `NOLOCK` isn't quite what you think it is. `NOLOCK` still takes out `Sch-S` (schema stability) locks on the related objects so it can still get blocked if there is an in-progress transaction elsewhere that has been modifying those objects and has an `Sch-M` (schema modification) lock on them, e.g.: alter/create table, alter/create index, index rebuilds and optimizations, etc..

Comment: Are you really using SQL Server 2008 since it went out of support?  Also I recall SQL Server 2008 does not allow online index rebuilds even if you attempt to code it that way so perhaps you were running index maintenance during the off-hours you mention.  Index maintenance in particular makes tables un-expectantly inaccessible in these older versions.

Answer (score 1):

NOLOCK is never applyed on SELECT queries involved into INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs, MERGEs and **SELECT ... INTO**s.

Also NOLOCK won't be applyed when ENCRYPT / DECRYPT functions are used...

Imagine just what is NOLOCK... NOLOCK is not the fact that your query will not block other users, but will ignore locks that other users have sets...
This conducts to read sometime twice or more the same row, or to avoid readings some rows... It is just unacceptable to guarantee data integrity when the database queries are writting data into table/indexes !